# Как создать и удалить элемент с помощью jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Есть скрипт выдвижной панели. В файле стиля есть элемент (подложка), который в html код не добавлен. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы скрипт при активации панели создавал этот элемент, а при закрытии панели удалял его? При добавлении `$('.sidebar').appendTo('<div id="sidebar_bg"></div>');`  элемент создается, но при закрытии панели не удаляется. Благодарю!

```js
$(function(){
  $('.sidebar_icon').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar_toggled');
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar_bg {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 top: 30px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 99;
}
.sidebar {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: -300px;
 width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
 -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 -o-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 z-index: 100;
}
.sidebar_toggled { left: 0; }
.sidebar_icon {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: blue;
z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="sidebar_icon"></div>
```

Comment: а добавить в раметку .sidebar_bg и с помощью toggle показывать?  пример - https://jsfiddle.net/2mhv09n6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#sidebar_bg').remove();` - удалить элемент

```js
$(function(){
  $('.sidebar_icon').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#sidebar_bg').length == 0) {
      $('.sidebar').append('<div id="sidebar_bg"></div>');
    } else {
      $('#sidebar_bg').remove();
    }
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar_toggled');
  });
});
```

```css
#sidebar_bg {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 top: 30px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 99;
}
.sidebar {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: -300px;
 width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
 -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 -o-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 transition:all 200ms ease-in;
 z-index: 100;
}
.sidebar_toggled { left: 0; }
.sidebar_icon {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: blue;
z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="sidebar_icon"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить проверку  в конце события на наличие класса , и в случае если он есть , удалять все дивы из "sidebar"

```
if ($('.sidebar').hasClass('sidebar_toggled')) {
   $('.sidebar div').remove();
}
```